# What happens if we don't enable "interactivity and shortcuts" option in slack api?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-block-kit

I'm trying to create a slack app. And am planning to use a button for my slack app to give the message a better look even though the same was possible through a link in the message.
[image]

And was successful in doing so. However, i'm seeing this message:

[image]

The button is basically a link to an external site so i'm not sure if I should enable the interactive and shortcuts option in the slack api. Is there any side-effect during production, if I don't enable it?

Answer (score 2):

The [button component](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements#button) requires the `interactivity and shortcut` option to be enabled. Once you do so, clicking on this button will send a payload to your server (you could also set up a [serverless function](https://api.slack.com/docs/hosting) for this). Your server will need to respond back with an [acknowledgment response](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/handling#acknowledgment_response).

If you don't enable interactivity and shortcut, users will also see this error message in your screenshot.